# Autoresizing UICollectionView: first UICollectionViewCell overlaps

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, overlap

Im working on an iOS app in Swift, using a UICollectionView. I’m autosizing collection view cells:

```
if let cvl = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
    cvl.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: 240, height: 70)
}
```

It is working fine, every cell is autosized perfectly. But I have an issue when I rotated the device.

If first cell is not visible and device is rotated, then scrolling to top in order to make first cell visible -> all cells are autosized correctly, but first cell is overlapped. Not getting any warning or message on Debug Area.

[First cell overlapped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7uJP.jpg)

If first cell is visible and device is rotated -> all cells are autosized correctly, first cell not is overlapped.

[First cell non overlapped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JEopM.jpg)

Does anyone have any idea what is going on?

Comment: set dynamic size refer link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23760275/dynamic-size-uicollectionview-cell

Comment: I think that is the old way before iOS8. I'm using [Autosizing Collection View Cells](https://goo.gl/lp18tZ) , this feature was introduced with iOS8.