# How to set Multiple Size/Merge cells in UICollection View

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I want to make a layout using `UICollectionVIew`. But I am not sure it is possible or not.

I have tried changing `height` of one `Cell` but it is not working. Here is the layout which  I want to acheive:

[image]

In this Layout height of each cell is fixed only the height and width of first cell is different.

How can I achieve this.

Comment: It is possible : [Dynamic size UICollectionView cell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23760275/dynamic-size-uicollectionview-cell)

Comment: @the_UB I tried this way earlier...but it is not working

Comment: You'll need to make your own subclass of `UICollectionViewLayout` and define the attributes (specifically, the `frame`) for each index path.