# easy way to use sizeForItemAtIndexPath with UICollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have check a lot of links regarding this but i could not come to a conclusion. What i want to do is have dynamic size for cells of a UICollectionView. I have an array of images with different sizes and i want to display them. I can't figure out why other answers on SO are so complicated for this problem, what i understand is, i just need to calculate the size of image in the sizeForItemAtIndexPath method as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23760275/dynamic-size-uicollectionview-cell) but i am getting an error, `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFConstantString size]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10fc860a0`
My implementation for sizeForItemAtIndexPath is as,

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
              layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout
sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UIImage *image = [arrRecipeImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    CGSize size = CGSizeMake(image.size.width, image.size.height);
    return size;
}
```

Everything looks  fine to me, can someone point out where i am going wrong, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Look carefully at the error : `[__NSCFConstantString size]`. It looks like you are trying to call the `size` method on a string object.

Are you sure that `arrRecipeImages` is made of images ? You explicitly cast your item from the array as an `UIImage` object, but it can be anything.

Comment: yes, code works fine and all images are displayed if i comment out sizeForItemAtIndexPath method.

Comment: Can you edit your question and add your `cellForItemAtIndexPath` method ?

Comment: Thanks for your hint, i changed the previous code with `UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:[arrRecipeImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];`, the error is gone but not all the images are displayed.