# How to change UICollectionview Cell Height dynamically?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a `UICollectionView` and a custom `UIcollectionViewCell`.
Inside that cell there is one `UITableView`.

The content of the tableview changes dynamically so it's height also changes dynamically.
I want `UICollectionViewCell` to change it's height with respect to the tableview inside the Collectionviewcell.

How to do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamic size UICollectionView cell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23760275/dynamic-size-uicollectionview-cell)

Answer (score 1):

Use collectionView's delegate for setting size to cell,

**Objective-C**

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
              layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout
  sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

      NSLog(@"SETTING SIZE FOR ITEM AT INDEX %d", indexPath.row);

      //Calculate the height required for tableView inside the cell and set it to the cell
      return CGSizeMake(80, 80);
}
```

**Swift**

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {

      NSLog(@"SETTING SIZE FOR ITEM AT INDEX %d", indexPath.row);

      //Calculate the height required for tableView inside the cell and set it to the cell
      return CGSizeMake(80, 80);
}
```

Hope it helps you.