# UICollectionView with differently sized cells

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

A collection view that is 3 cells wide and x cells tall, however randomly spread throughout i'd like a cell that is the size of 2 cells, see the image below

[image]

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking or what you've tried so far. However, if you're trying to lay out a collection view like that you will undoubtedly need to subclass your own `UICollectionViewLayout` to decide where each cell should appear and at what size.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamic size UICollectionView cell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23760275/dynamic-size-uicollectionview-cell)

Comment: have a look at [THIS](https://github.com/betzerra/MosaicLayout). It might just be what you need

Answer (score 1):

This will require a custom subclass of UICollectionViewLayout, which will manage both position and size of the items in the way you want.

Or you can get a layout somebody else already made, for example RFQuiltLayout:

https://github.com/bryceredd/RFQuiltLayout

https://cocoapods.org/pods/RFQuiltLayout