# how to fit the image in tableview based on size and Aspect ration?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

I am developing the project like Instagram upload the image and display the all feeds in home page.But image not fitting in image view. In Instagram table view cell automatically fit based on image size please provide me suggestions.

Comment: get image size from server or first download image and find aspect ratio (size) of image

Comment: how we will get the image size from server?. How will send the aspect ration to server ?

Comment: I want to make image like mentioned URL https://havecamerawilltravel.com/photographer/instagram-square

Comment: have a look at : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23760275/dynamic-size-uicollectionview-cell

Answer (score 1):

```
[_imageView setImage:[ViewController imageWithContentMode:[UIImage imageNamed:@"howwehelp_bg.png"] withScaledSize:_imageView.bounds.size]];

_imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;

+(UIImage *)imageWithContentMode:(UIImage *)image withScaledSize:(CGSize)newSize{

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 0.0);

[image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];

UIImage *imageNew = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

return imageNew;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply this code for fit images.

```
+(UIImage*)imageWithImage: (UIImage*) sourceImage scaledToWidth: (float) i_width
{
float oldWidth = sourceImage.size.width;
float scaleFactor = i_width / oldWidth;

float newHeight = sourceImage.size.height * scaleFactor;
float newWidth = oldWidth * scaleFactor;

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(newWidth, newHeight));
[sourceImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newWidth, newHeight)];
UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();    
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
return newImage;
```

}