# How to implement Grid Layout for ios

Tags: ios, layout

How to implement Grid layout for ios? There are similar layouts: `<Grid>` in windows `xaml` and `<GridLayout>` in android, but I failed to find any resource which covers how to implement similar thing in ios.

In brief: there are should be so called "Grid" in which I specify how many rows and cells are there and then I can specify that some particular control (for ex. `TextView`) should start at `x` column and span `w` columns, start at `y` row and span `h` rows.

Update: don't confuse `GridControl` with `GridLayout`, an example of `GridLayout`:
[image]

Comment: `UICollectionVIew`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to implement GridLayout with help of the following blog article:
https://web.archive.org/web/20170620013903/http://blog.stablekernel.com/creating-a-custom-uicollectionviewlayout

In brief I had to implement my own UICollectionViewLayout, but I didn't need the complexity as it was presented in the article.

The problem with this solution is cell reusing, which I don't need and there is no way to switch it off.

Comment: @OlivierMATROT I use C# and solution was not universal, but for specific task. This code I copied from an early prototype which later was improved, but the idea comes from it, You can take a look at it https://gist.github.com/Mogikan/b4bc79f1decf553f4e18c3a6ba387620#file-gridcontrol-cs

Comment: @OlivierMATROT gist from the article: https://gist.github.com/smswz/393b2d6237b7837234015805c600ada2

Answer (score 3):

Use collectionviews to write grid layout

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview

Answer (score 2):

Use a [UICollectionView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview) for Grid Layout. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17856406/7456236) answer which shows the integration of `UICollectionView` in details

For such a layout also, you need to use `collectionView` itself, but use the `sizeForItemAtIndexPath` dataSource properly. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25275878/7456236) answer. Also try to customize `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`

Also [this](https://github.com/betzerra/MosaicLayout) is an awesome library which also do the same thing for you

Comment: You are talking about GridView and this is a different control. I didn't find any sample which allows cell to span for several rows and columns.

Comment: @AccessDenied For that also, you need to use collectionView itself, but use the `sizeForItemAtIndexPath` dataSource properly. Check this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/25275878/7456236

Also this library also do the same thing for you : https://github.com/betzerra/MosaicLayout

Comment: Your answer was not 100% correct, mozaic view is a different thing. I've added link in the answer which does exactly what I needed.

Comment: Ok. Anyway Happy it helped you  :)

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to find out how xamarin implemented GridLayout and try to reproduce it.
https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Core/GridCalc.cs

Answer (score 0):

One more way to implement it is to inherit from UIView and override LayoutSubviews method and set children Frame manually.